# Google maps not showing in Foundation sections

Tags: google-maps-api-3, zurb-foundation

I have the same question as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299665/google-maps-resize-issue-with-foundation-css-sections) but provided no accepted answer has been given and that my procedure is different, I'm opening a new one.

I have a map inside a Foundation tab that is hidden at the beginning and it only displays part of the map when opened. I've read the [issues](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/165) related to that and tried the attempts there but no luck. I know I have to re-initialize the map on tab change but I can't make it work.

I have a function that holds all the map info:

```js
function startMap(obj){
    var markers = new Array();
    var glat_center = $(obj).attr('data-glat');
    var glong_center = $(obj).attr('data-glong');
    var Latlng_center = new google.maps.LatLng(glat_center, glong_center);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: zoom,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: Latlng_center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: mapStyles,
      mapTypeControl: false, 
      streetViewControl: false,
      minZoom: 4,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
      }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(obj, mapOptions);
    if($(obj).attr('data-glat') && $(obj).attr('data-glong')){
        var glat = $(obj).attr('data-glat');
        var glong = $(obj).attr('data-glong');
        var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(glat, glong);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: Latlng,
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```

My html markup looks like this

```html
<div class="tabs" data-section="auto">
<!--two more tabs here-->
<section class="property-location">
    <a href="#" class="title" data-section-title>Title</a>
        <div class="tab-content" data-slug="section3" data-section-content>
        <div class="google-map" data-glat="123456" data-glong="123456" style="width: 100%; height: 440px;">
    </div>
        </div>
</section>
</div>
```

So then, what I'm trying to do is call this function when the tab is clicked, as I can't find any other tab events in Foundation docs. First I find the .title of the tab that contains the map, then look if a map exists (just in case) and then I call the function on the div holding the map.

```js
$('.tabs .property-location').find('.title').click(function() {
    if(($('.tab-content').find('.google-map')).length) {
        //console.log('I found a map');
        startMap($('.google-map'));
    }
});
```

I know it's finding the map because I console.log it, but the console throws this error

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
```

which is on the following src `http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/es_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/14/7/main.js`

So it's the Google Maps JS that's throwing this error but I can't understand why.

I know it's difficult, but any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a jQuery-element, but google maps needs a `HTMLElement`. Use

```js
var map = document.querySelector('.google-map');
startMap(map);
```

instead of

```js
startMap($('.google-map'));
```

---

Instead of `querySelector` you can use `getElementsByClassName`

```js
var map = document.getElementsByClassName('google-map')[0];
```

But the always recommended approach is to refer to the map by an `id` :

```
<div id="the-google-map" class="google-map" data-glat="123456" data-glong="123456" style="width: 100%; height: 440px;"></div>
```

```js
var map = document.getElementById('the-google-map');
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I'm really JS newbie and I'd have taken me forever to understand what was going on... Why is the `id` approach recommended, is it faster? Anyway, now is working and I have added some code to check if the map is already loaded so I don't load it every time.

Comment: Gr8! Yes - http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector - but it is not something one should care about when there is one element only. getElementById is just how all the google examples are coded, and the logically choice since you always will target a single element at a time anyway, when creating a google map.